# Javascript/jQuery legend widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, legend

Is there a JS/jQuery widget that would allow me to display a simple legend that contains for example a small colored rectanlge and a text label next to it?

In this specific case the legend would show meanings behind different color codes in an inline jQuery UI datepicker widget, which would be customized to enable multiple selections by a user and showing different colors for specific days.

In fact, the thing that I need would look exactly like the list of SO sites at the footer of this page (but ideally listed vertically next to the picker). So if there is no ready-made solution I guess I'll try and look at this page source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hand it to the StackOverflow crew. Their method for creating the legends is pretty clever. Basically, they use the character ■ (ASCII 254) in place of any image or div. They insert it in a span, which is styled with a font size and color property. Next to it is a styled anchor tag. Rinse and repeat.

What is particularly clever about it is that it all fits inline in a div *and lines  up on the baseline*! Let me say that again: *it lines up on the baseline*! So there is no disparity in image offsets, etc. A tip of the hat to the UI engineer who made it that simple. Thanks for calling my attention to that, or I probably never would have looked and learned.

EDIT: ASCII 254 is incorrect. The actual value yielded by `"■".charCodeAt(0)` is 9632 and is probably some flavor of Unicode. Same look and shape, but different value.